# rotating image not working properly

Tags: css, animation

My example/work: http://thomasdebelder.be/1/
I'm trying to rotate a moon, planet like this: https://www.google.com/doodles/new-horizons-pluto-flyby but it doesnt work, I tryed in my css code to  transform:rotate it with 180 and 360 deg, rotating it around the X, with transform-origin:center but it still rotates badly. It needs rotate around the center, like in the google link not from left to right.

`@keyframes moon {
100% {
    transform:rotate(180deg);
}}`

```
      <!-- MOON -->
        <div class="moon">
        <img src="images/moon.png">
        </div>
```

Comment: Google is using a gif to create that animation as you can see it here http:////www.google.com/logos/doodles/2015/new-horizons-pluto-flyby-5641113681526784.4-hp2x.gif

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a transform-origin: 50% 50% to make this turn around the center

Answer (score 0):

Add `transform-origin: center center;` to the image.